# Use C# variables for cmd strings

Tags: c#, variables, cmd

I have a C# script and I want to use some of the variables I've declared in a cmd command:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace UserMake
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string userName;
            string passWord;

            Console.WriteLine("Enter a username:");
            userName = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a password:");
            passWord = Console.ReadLine();
            Process.Start("cmd","net user userName passWord /add");
        } 
    }
}
```

I can't work out how to get the 'userName' and 'passWord' to read as the variable set rather than making a user called 'userName' with password 'passWord'.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [string concatenation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228504.aspx):

```
Process.Start("cmd","net user" +  userName + " " + passWord + " /add");
```

Alternatively, you could use [`string.Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx):

```
Process.Start(string.Format("net user {0} {1} /add", userName, passWord));
```

Answer (score 2):

You should insert the variable values concatenating them to the string passed as Argument to the Process.Start method

```
Process.Start("cmd","net user " + userName + " " + passWord  + " /add");
```

However, your command, as written, doesn't work. The correct command should be

```
Process.Start("cmd","/C net user " + userName + " " + passWord  + " /add");
```

Comment: I tried all of that, the concentrating didn't work. Thanks but Andrew and John helped with the string.Format. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Strange, this is functionally the same thing. I can only think to one problem. Have you placed the correct spaces after and before the strings? By the way, the accepted answer shows two wrong examples. The first one lacks a space between `net user` and the concatenated user name. The second example doesn't have the cmd command at all. Well... let's go and thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Aside from concatenating the string, you can use **[`String.Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx)**

```
Process.Start("cmd", string.Format("net user {0} {1} /add", userName, passWord);
```